# How to create DLL file from C source code in Postgres to create extension

Tags: windows, visual-studio, postgresql

I have a .C file and some postgres header files. To create an extension in PostgreSQL, I need a DLL file for that to put in the library folder. How can I turn the .c file into a PostgreSQL extension DLL?

---

*Question rewritten from original for clarity.*

Comment: By Googling for *postgres extension tutorial* ?

Comment: @AlexK. Actually I have a **.C** file having some postgres header files.And to create an extension in Postgres, I need  a **DLL** file for that to put in the library folder.

Comment: I should really just close-vote this as "too broad", especially since you don't seem to have made an effort to solve the problem yourself first, but I know it's not well documented, so posting an answer. It's link-mostly, but I can't post a fully detailed answer without writing a giant answer that duplicates what I've written elsewhere, and I'm not doing that - especially for a zero-effort question. Be glad I'm not replying with "How to use google?" :p

Comment: @CraigRinger It's not a zero effort question but I don't want to use **Visual studio** for this.And  I got all results for Unix Systems not for windows machine.

Comment: @ripunj2408813 By "zero effort" I only mean that you *showed* no evidence of having tried to solve the problem before posting, or sign of effort posting a detailed question that makes what you're doing clear. As for Visual Studio: if you don't want to to use it, what *do* you want to use? Why *not* Visual Studio? If it's cost, just use Visual Studio Express. If you want to automate, did you know that MSBuild can run VS project files? Alternately you could use `nmake`, or you could use Mingw32, msys and unix `make` on Windows.

Comment: @CraigRinger I have used Mingw32 and use make command to install MakeFile but it shows **pgxs.mk** file not found in lib directory of postgres.

Comment: @ripunj2408813 `pgxs` isn't supported on Windows (at least in 9.5 and older, it might be in later versions). So you can't use it to build extensions on Windows. You *can* put the extension directory into `contrib/[extname]` in a source tree and build the whole source tree though, per my answer.

Comment: @CraigRinger I have put all .control and .sql and .c file in contrib directory and run **make Makefile install** command and then it says **pg_config**: command not found

Comment: @ripunj2408813 You need a full source tree and you must use the Windows build infrastructure (src/tools/msvc/). See the link provided. Might be possible with mingw32 too but I never wanted to so haven't investigated. You ignored my question: why not just use msvc?

Comment: @CraigRinger Hey CraigRinger !!...Can I create folder or directory by writing  query in postgres?

Comment: @ripunj2408813 Please post a new question for a new topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [wrote a blog article detailing this a while ago](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/); you should probably start there. There's also a [wiki page on postgresql.org](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Building_and_Installing_PostgreSQL_Extension_Modules).

The process is more than can really be posted as a standalone answer here, but the greatly simplified summary is:

- Create a Visual Studio DLL project
- Add PostgreSQL headers and libraries to the project
- Set up some preprocessor directives required for compiling a PostgreSQL extension
- Compile it

---

Alternately, you can prepare a PostgreSQL source tree, create a `contrib/mymodule` directory, [create a `Makefile` there using the same PGXS options as for UNIX](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-pgxs.html), then compile the whole PostgreSQL source tree using the Windows build scripts as documented [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/install-windows-full.html). Doing it this way means you don't have to make a Visual Studio project, but you instead have to do a full source code build of PostgreSQL, so it's probably not any better.